# JSON response from Spring REST has backslash characters

Tags: json, spring, rest

I have my Spring REST service written like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> 
            getStudentByName(@PathVariable("name") String name)  {
    Map<String, Object> map = null;
    try {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", "Tom Joe);
        map.put("id", "t100");
        map.put("dept", "nuclear energy");          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error finding with name " + name, e);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I get the output like this on the client side which is basically a single string:

```
"{\"name\":\"Tom Joe\",\"id\":\"100\",\"dept\":\"nuclear energy\"}"
```

But my desired output is:

```
{
"name":"Tom Joe",
"id":"t100",
"dept":"nuclear energy"
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to avoid sending backslashes and instead send proper json ? Can I not do that for returning a map ?

Comment: I would try produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON instead, the mime type APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE is giving you a string conversion of that.

Comment: @Tim That wouldn't compile. `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` is a `MediaType` value. `produces` expects `String[]`.

Comment: Not sure why my below answer was downvoted but the code seems to work fine.. I would check which client you're using, if it's a java client it may be adding the escape characters to the response when displaying it.

Comment: @AdamSmith http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Fair enough, the main reason I posted it as an answer was so I could add code formatting to show that I was putting it inside a plain RestController which may not have been what the OP was doing, and also so I could show the response I was getting was properly formatted as he was expecting it.. it wasn't just a simple "Well it works for me" reply..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tried your code in my application and it seemed to be working as expected:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

...

@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getStudentByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    Map<String, Object> map = null;
    try {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("name", "Tom Joe");
        map.put("id", "t100");
        map.put("dept", "nuclear energy");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error finding with name " + name, e);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Gives the following output:

> {"name":"Tom Joe","id":"t100","dept":"nuclear energy"}

Which client are you using? I'm using Advanced Rest client in chrome.

Comment: Surprising. I am using my own java client to test. Basically, creating HttpURLConnection and getting the response using its inputstream. I get the response but it is one single string instead of good json.

Comment: have you tried it in a browser?

Comment: you are right. Service is indeed returning proper json but Gson.toJson(response) is adding those backslashes. Sorry for the post!

Comment: No worries.  If you want to accept this as the answer, feel free :)